# SSAS - Weird filtering issue that was fixed by clearing the cube cache?

Tags: ssas

We had an very weird issue this morning with our cube whereby a pivot table we were refreshing in Excel was producing null values for some of our measures. The same MDX query run in SSMS also produced the same result so it wasn't an Excel issue.

What we were finding is that if we filter the list of members (on the heading of the table, not in the filter list), it would bring back those members but no data in the measures (except one of the calculated measures it would). If we removed that filter and used the `All` member, then those members would have data. Another way we could get data to appear was by including the Unknown member, or removing another dimension attribute from the pivot. This made absolutely no sense.

The even weirder thing was that it was only specific days. Yesterday for example had this effect, but the day before didn't, then the day before that did. All this data exists on the same partition so it wasn't a partition issue.

We ended up clearing the cache by running the following, which fixed the issue.

`<ClearCache xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>Data Warehouse</DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>Retail</CubeID>
  </Object>
</ClearCache>`

I have no idea why clearing the cache fixed our issue. I don't know much about the cache, but why would clearing it fix our issue? We are concerned now that data may be incorrect or not showing at all under certain circumstances and don't want to have to stop trusting the cache and refresh it every day.

The other thing is that the profiler when I was running the query doesn't show anything about hitting the cache. All I see is it running `REFRESH CUBE [Retail]`.

Comment: By any chance are you using scope statements within your cube?  As well, just to confirm, did you open up SQL Profiler and ensure to include reviewing the query processing events (which includes cache) as I do not believe they are on by default.

Comment: No we don't use any scope statements. I didn't add these events, however I never do and usually see cache hits. Before we saw this weird behaviour, we only 5 minutes earlier processed the partition that this data is on. So, I'm thinking that somehow in the process of processing this partition, the cache either didn't update correctly, or something funny happened with it.

Comment: By any chance do you have lazy processing on?  What could be happening is that when you process the partition and sees and update in the dimension (i.e. ProcessUpdate), it invalidates the aggregations and indexes for your partition (which is why you get nothing when you query it). Running clear cache would force the query engine to run the query without use of aggregations or indexes hence the result back.